# How can the browser be notified to fill saved username and password in a form created by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autofill

My website has a few registered users, so I decided it is inefficient to put a `login form` in the page while only a few people actually use it. Then I put a `button` whose `onclick event` triggers a `javascript` function that creates a `login form` and displays it on the page.

The problem is that when the user fires this function and the login form is displayed (for the first time), the `user name` and `password` `inputs` do not fill with the `saved values` by the browser (Chrome, IE, FireFox).

(After closing and reopening the form, it's fields fills with the saved values, which is desirable)

How should I notify the browser to fill fields with the saved username and password?

Thank you very much.

HTML seems something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="loginform"></div>
<a id="linktologinform" href="loginpage.html" onclick="return !showloginform();" >members</a>
<div id="mainbody">
main contents
</div>
</body>
```

and the javascript:

```
function showloginform()
{
var form='<form action="login.php"><input type="text" name="username"/><input type="password" name="password"/></form><a onclick="document.getElementById(\'loginform\').style.display=\'none\';">close</a>';
document.getElementById("loginform").innerHtml=form;
document.getElementById("loginform").style.display="block";
return true;
}
```

Comment: You are using double and single quotes inside in your form html. That's messing up. I guess to fix your problem you should include your form in your main html and just use JS to hide / show it.

Comment: @Doodlebunch in the main code, I have used double quotes everywhere. The size of this login form is somehow big and I wanted to avoid loading that when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Ormoz i think he's referencing your usage of `'` inside of a string that is also wrapped in `'`. For example, `'Hello World! It's Broken~'` note the inner `'`, which will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Also, i see your edit, it still has yet another error. you can't escape quotes in an attribute with backslashes, instead you have to use html entities. `&quot;`

Comment: @Kevin B That's what I meant. Didn't know how to explain it properly.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry I have rewritten this javascript here and it has some syntax errors but the real code works fine.

Comment: @Doodlebunch , You were right. I edited the quotes.Now, it seems like the original one which works properly.

Comment: Trying to write something like this yourself and make it secure is going to be a lot of work - is there an existing framework you could use to do this? You could put the username in a cookie, but you really don't want to store a password in a cookie. Many browsers have an autocomplete feature the user can turn on or off - if they want to store it, let the autocomplete do it.

Comment: @Tim as I figgured out, when the page loads, the form does not exists, So when later the form is created, the browser does not notice its existence and do not fill the fields. when hiding the form with the close button and reopening it, this time the browser distinguish the form and fills username and password as it is needed.

Comment: If it's created through script, you want to populate it at page load, and it needs to persist across sessions (user closes their browser and comes back tomorrow for instance), you'll need to use a cookie. Just read the username out of the cookie and set the value of the input with it.